# how to tell when mongoosejs findOneAndUpdate method succeeds?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How can I tell when findOneAndUpdate successfully updates a document?  `huh` variable always returns the same thing (whether id is in the database or not) and doc is always null.

```
var query = {id : id };
var huh = schemaModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, obj, function(doc) {
        console.log(doc);
        if(doc) {
            callback(doc);
        } else {
            errback('');
        }
    }
);
console.log(huh);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only passing one parameter to the `callback` in your `findOneAndUpdate` query.

I think that your query succeeds, but `doc` will always come `null` when you successfully update the object as it is the first parameter which is the `err`.

Also, I do not see the code for your `callback` function, so I am just presuming that it can be accessed in the scope of your function.

```
var query = {id : id };
var huh = schemaModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, obj, function(err, doc) {

        if(err) {
            return "Error spotted!";
        } else {
            return "Found & Updated";
        }
    }
);
console.log(huh);
```

By returning those values, you are basically assigning them to the `huh` variable and it should log accordingly. It serves as a logging mechanism.